# Weird symbols after generating excel file from html table

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I am trying to generate excel file after button is clicked. I made it as form:

```
<form method="post" action="ExcelStudio.php" target="_blank" style="float:right;">
    <input type="submit" name="export_excel_studio" class="button" value="Studio Report"></input>
</form>
```

So after submitting form I proceed to generating excel file:

```
<?php
require_once ('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include('inc/database_connection.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME); 

$output = '';
$conn->set_charset('utf8_unicode_ci');//if not by default
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$F = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

if(isset($_POST["export_excel_studio"]))
{
    // 1.Get data
    $sql2 = '
                select
                  p2.proc_leader as username,
                       max(case when studio = "APEX" then "x" else "" end) as APEX,
                       max(case when studio = "BASECAMP" then "x" else "" end) as BASECAMP,
                       max(case when studio = "CANVAS" then "x" else "" end) as CANVAS,
                       max(case when studio = "HORIZON" then "x" else "" end) as HORIZON,
                       max(case when studio = "LAUNCHPAD" then "x" else "" end) as LAUNCHPAD,
                       max(case when studio = "NEBULA" then "x" else "" end) as NEBULA,
                       max(case when studio = "ORBIT" then "x" else "" end) as ORBIT,
                       max(case when studio = "PALETTE" then "x" else "" end) as PALETTE,
                       max(case when studio = "SANDBOX" then "x" else "" end) as SANDBOX,
                       max(case when studio = "STELLAR" then "x" else "" end) as STELLAR,
                       max(case when studio = "THE CLIMB" then "x" else "" end) as THECLIMB,
                       max(case when studio = "TOONIGAMI" then "x" else "" end) as TOONIGAMI,
                       max(case when studio = "TREEHOUSE" then "x" else "" end) as TREEHOUSE
                from process p1
                left join (
                  select *
                  from proc_leader
                  union all
                  select *
                  from proc_checker
                  union all
                  select *
                  from proc_staff    
                ) p2 on p1.projectNo = p2.projectNo
                and p1.process = p2.process
                group by p2.proc_leader
    ';
    // 2. Output table
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    $header = '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">Username</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio APEX</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio BASECAMP</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio CANVAS</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio HORIZON</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio LAUNCHPAD</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio NEBULA</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio ORBIT</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio PALETTE</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio SANDBOX</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio STELLAR</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio THECLIMB</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio TOONIGAMI</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio TREEHOUSE</th>';
        $body = '';
    while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $username = $data2['username'];
        $apex = $data2['APEX'];
        $basecamp = $data2['BASECAMP'];
        $canvas = $data2['CANVAS'];
        $horizon = $data2['HORIZON'];
        $launchpad = $data2['LAUNCHPAD'];
        $nebula = $data2['NEBULA'];
        $orbit = $data2['ORBIT'];
        $palette = $data2['PALETTE'];
        $sandbox = $data2['SANDBOX'];
        $stellar = $data2['STELLAR'];
        $theclimb = $data2['THECLIMB'];
        $toonigame = $data2['TOONIGAMI'];
        $treehouse = $data2['TREEHOUSE'];

        $row = '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . htmlspecialchars($username) . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $apex . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $basecamp . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $canvas . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $horizon . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $launchpad . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $nebula . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $orbit . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $palette . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $sandbox . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $stellar . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $theclimb . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $toonigame . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $treehouse . '</td>';
        $body .= "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>$row</tr>";
    }       
    $output .= "
            <table class='table' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                <thead><tr>$header</tr></thead>
                <tbody>$body</tbody>
            </table>
        ";

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="StudioReport.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    echo $output;
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;           
}
```

It works fine except one thing, I got weird symbols after table. So I think it means that there is a problem somewhere. here is what i got after opening excel file[image: got after opening excel file]. What could be a problem and how can I solve this? Thank you

Comment: Remember to use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` too, maybe that has something to do.

Comment: @LordNeo didnt help

Comment: Either send the file to the browser, ___or___ send html markup; but not both.... the browser (and the http protocol) can only response per request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by changing file:

```
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=StudioReport.xls" );
include('inc/database_connection.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME); 

$output = '';
$conn->set_charset('utf8_unicode_ci');//if not by default   
// print your data here. note the following:
// - cells/columns are separated by tabs ("\t")
// - rows are separated by newlines ("\n")

if(isset($_POST["export_excel_studio"]))
{
    // 1.Get data
    $sql2 = '
                select
                  p2.proc_leader as username,
                       max(case when studio = "APEX" then "x" else "" end) as APEX,
                       max(case when studio = "BASECAMP" then "x" else "" end) as BASECAMP,
                       max(case when studio = "CANVAS" then "x" else "" end) as CANVAS,
                       max(case when studio = "HORIZON" then "x" else "" end) as HORIZON,
                       max(case when studio = "LAUNCHPAD" then "x" else "" end) as LAUNCHPAD,
                       max(case when studio = "NEBULA" then "x" else "" end) as NEBULA,
                       max(case when studio = "ORBIT" then "x" else "" end) as ORBIT,
                       max(case when studio = "PALETTE" then "x" else "" end) as PALETTE,
                       max(case when studio = "SANDBOX" then "x" else "" end) as SANDBOX,
                       max(case when studio = "STELLAR" then "x" else "" end) as STELLAR,
                       max(case when studio = "THE CLIMB" then "x" else "" end) as THECLIMB,
                       max(case when studio = "TOONIGAMI" then "x" else "" end) as TOONIGAMI,
                       max(case when studio = "TREEHOUSE" then "x" else "" end) as TREEHOUSE
                from process p1
                left join (
                  select *
                  from proc_leader
                  union all
                  select *
                  from proc_checker
                  union all
                  select *
                  from proc_staff    
                ) p2 on p1.projectNo = p2.projectNo
                and p1.process = p2.process
                group by p2.proc_leader
    ';  
    // 2. Output table
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    $header = '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">Username</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio APEX</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio BASECAMP</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio CANVAS</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio HORIZON</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio LAUNCHPAD</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio NEBULA</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio ORBIT</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio PALETTE</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio SANDBOX</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio STELLAR</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio THECLIMB</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio TOONIGAMI</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Studio TREEHOUSE</th>';
        $body = '';
    while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $username = $data2['username'];
        $apex = $data2['APEX'];
        $basecamp = $data2['BASECAMP'];
        $canvas = $data2['CANVAS'];
        $horizon = $data2['HORIZON'];
        $launchpad = $data2['LAUNCHPAD'];
        $nebula = $data2['NEBULA'];
        $orbit = $data2['ORBIT'];
        $palette = $data2['PALETTE'];
        $sandbox = $data2['SANDBOX'];
        $stellar = $data2['STELLAR'];
        $theclimb = $data2['THECLIMB'];
        $toonigame = $data2['TOONIGAMI'];
        $treehouse = $data2['TREEHOUSE'];

        $row = '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . htmlspecialchars($username) . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $apex . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $basecamp . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $canvas . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $horizon . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $launchpad . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $nebula . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $orbit . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $palette . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $sandbox . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $stellar . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $theclimb . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $toonigame . '</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $treehouse . '</td>';
        $body .= "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>$row</tr>";
    }       
    $output .= "
            <table class='table' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                <thead><tr>$header</tr></thead>
                <tbody>$body</tbody>
            </table>
        ";
    echo $output;       
}
```